# Criar mais campos e evitar JOIN diminui carga?

Tags: php, mysql, join

Tenho 3 tabelas que estão ligadas:

```
1ª tabela: 
GRADE (grade de horários)
Campos: ID - GRADE - ESTADO - VALIDADE 

2ª tabela: 
BLOCOS (blocos de horários da grade)
Campos: ID - ID_GRADE - BLOCO - DIA_SEMANA - DURACAO

3ª Tabela:
COMERCIAIS
resumidamente estes campos: ID, ID_CLENTE, ID_GRADE, ID_BLOCO
```

Estou usando uma `FK` para ligar os IDs as suas respectivas referencias nas tabelas.

Minha duvida é: Na 3ª tabela pode ser ver a chave estrangeira o `ID_GRADE`, que também está na 2ª e eu coloquei ela pensando em diminuir a carga no banco de dados, pois se por ventura eu tentar colocar a tabela GRADE em `ESTADO-> desativado`, o sistema antes irá procurar se ha algum registro a ser executado antes de mudar seu estado para desativado.

Sei que poderia fazer isso usando `JOIN` na tabela BLOCOS, mas penso que se posso guardar o `ID_GRADE`, eu evito usar `JOIN`, já que a tabela COMERCIAIS terá muitos registros.

Este meu pensamento está correto ou estou criando campos atoa ?

Comment: Procure ler sobre Modelagem e Formas Normais

Answer (score 1):

Não repita o campo, use o JOIN, crie um índice na coluna. 
Pense no relacionamento que existe entre suas entidades. Depois analise o desempenho da query.

Comment: Mas por exemplo na tabela GRADE eu tenho um campo que se chama ID_EMISSORA, este campo está ligado ao campo ID na tabela EMISSORAS

Mas na tabela COMERCIAIS eu preciso saber se aquele determinado registro é para  EMISSORA [1], [2], ou [3] 
Neste caso eu iria fazer um SELECT na tabela COMERCIAIS para que me retornasse apenas os registros da EMISSORA 1, neste caso eu teria que dar um JOIN na tabela BLOCOS e consequentemente outro JOIN na tabela GRADES.

É aconselhável fazer isso ou neste caso é melhor cadastrar o ID_EMISSORA também ?

Answer (score 1):

Não é muito recomendado de se fazer isto

**Prós:**

Você ganha em desempenho nas consultas;

Visivelmente é melhor de se consultar na tabela.

**Contras:**

Sua aplicação terá que tratar as duas tabelas quando tiver alteração;

Você perde em tamanho de disco, uma vez que a tabela ficará maior;

**--**

Há outros, mas acho que estes são os que devemos analisar mais.

Para não haver problema de desempenho o melhor mesmo é trabalhar com chaves primárias, fazer um trabalho em cima dos índices e manutenção deles.

Na empresa que eu trabalho temos tabelas com milhares de linhas e trabalhando direito com os índices fazemos consultas com ótimos desempenhos.

Pode pesquisar também sobre tunning de banco, mas isto é outra história também rs

Comment: neste caso eu iria guardar apenas o ID da tabela de referencia, para quando fosse por exemplo procurar todos os registro da GRADE ID 1 ele me retornasse sem usar JOIN e o mesmo não teria modificação direta, já que só seria permitido deletar uma GRADE se fosse feito diretamente no BANCO